# How to set up toolbar when hovering

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a sort of toolbar that shows up when you tap on a certain part of the screen, e.g. If I'm building a image editor, when the user clicks on the top of the screen it displays all the tools. Whats the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a popover view activated by a button?